# Xcode and Git Source Control : "The working copy XXXXX failed to commit files"

Tags: xcode, git, commit

I know this may be an ultra-newbie question, but - although I've been coding for like 18 years - it's been only a few days that I've been using Source Control for my project and I feel quite lost.

I have set up **Git** properly and, from time to time, I'm commiting the changes.

`(File -> Source Control -> Commit)`

**However :**

Whenever I try to delete a file (that initially existed) and then commit the changes, I'm getting an error like this :

> **The working copy "MY_COPY_NAME" failed to commit files**
>
> fatal: could not switch to "/the/path/of/the/file/i/just/deleted":  no
>   such file or directory

What's going on?

What should I do in order to commit the changes even after a file has been deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should run

```
git add -u your_file
```

the -u means you want to update the file you already added. Another possibility is

```
git rm your_file
```

And it's likely you get an error if Git does not find an inexisting

Answer (score 0):

To fix above error you should use below lines of code:

1. Open the command line [Terminal] and enter the following two commands:

> ```
> xcrun git config --global user.email your@Email.com
>
> xcrun git config --global user.name "Enter Your Name"
> ```